# A button should show/hide depending on whether or not there is value in input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Right now the button shows when input is added to the input field, but if I remove the input the button doesn't hide.

My only idea for a solution is to divide the function into 2 seperate ones.
That is, one that adds the input to the input field on click, and then another functions that keeps track of input.val, and controls the hide/show effect of the button.

Would that be a better way of doing it?

```
$("#peopleInPopup").on('click', '.list-group-item', function() {
  var peopleName = $(this).children("span").text();
  var peopleID = $(this).children("span").attr("class");
  var input = $("#friendsNames");
  input.val(input.val() + peopleName + "");
  if (input.val().length === 0) {
    $("#checkButton").toggle(false);
    console.log("button should NOT display");
  } else {
    console.log("button should display");
    $("#checkButton").toggle(true);
  }
  $("#checkButton").click(function() {
    var newParticipants = input.val();
    socket.emit("addParticipantsToConversation", newParticipants);
    $("#chatToInfo").append(", ", input.val());
    $("#friendsNames").val("");
    $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change", $("#pagefour"), {
      transition: "slidedown"
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: If you post your existing code, html and other relevant pieces to demonstrate the current issue it would help more than looking at an alternate solution to a problem we cannot reproduce.

Comment: Your right @Fran, but the thing is that, the items that can get added to the input field are generated programatically, so it would be to complicated to add to the question. But I definitely see your point

Comment: Asking the question `Would that be a better way of doing it?` implies that the code you are showing is a working solution and you just want confirmation if it is the best way to go. If that is the case then this question is primarily opinion based as it is not trying to solve an issue :( Without seeing the actual broken code it's hard to give you a none-guessing solution. Anyway, looks like you found a way :)

Comment: I see your point, except that I in my question explain that the code currently doesn't work. The question `would that be a better way of doing it?` is in regards to my own idea for a solution, a solution I was not sure would work

Answer (score 0):

Just use show and hide from jQuery instead, perhaps? I assume you want this to happen as the input is changing, so I've thrown in keyup (could use onChange or alternatives).

Tweaking your code slightly...

```
$('input').on('keyup', function (event) {
  let value = event.target.value;

  if (value && value !== '' && value.length > 0) {
    $('#myButton').show();
  } else {
    $('#myButton').hide();
  }
})
```

With a markup...

```
<input id='input' />
<button id='myButton'>GO</button>
```

And some sort of base style...

```
#go {
  display: none;
}
```

Do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

I actually just found a solution to my problem. The code below makes it work:

```js
$("#peopleInPopup").on('click', '.list-group-item', function(){
          var peopleName = $(this).children("span").text();
          var peopleID = $(this).children("span").attr("class");
          var input = $("#friendsNames");
          input.val(input.val() + peopleName + "");  
          $("#checkButton").toggle(true);
          $("#friendsNames").on('input', function(event) {
          if (this.value.length === 0) {
            console.log("Works!");
            $("#checkButton").toggle(false);
            console.log("button should NOT display");
          } else {
            console.log("button should display");
            $("#checkButton").toggle(true);
          }
          });
          $("#checkButton").click(function(){
            var newParticipants = input.val();
            socket.emit("addParticipantsToConversation", newParticipants);
            $("#chatToInfo").append(", ",input.val());
            $("#friendsNames").val("");
            $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change", $("#pagefour"), { transition: "slidedown" });
            });   
        });
```